# Unable to use PyQt5 imports

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I've been programming in python three for about a week now, and I'm trying to insert some of these imports below. Where it's marked is where I'm having errors that will state

```
from PyQt5 import QtSql, uic <=== Right here
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi <=== Right here
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtSql import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import  *
from PyQt5.QtCore import  *
import pyrebase
import sqlite3
```

Where it's marked is where I'm having errors that will state

```
Cannot find reference 'uic' in '__init__pyi'
```

Comment: Do you mean that without the first two lines, the other PyQt imports are successful? If yes, what system are you on, and how did you install PyQt?

Comment: @musicamante Thanks for replying! I'm getting an error on the 'uic' part of it and the 'loadUi' .I'm currently using Pycharm, and I'm not not quite sure how I installed it, but I believe it was through cmd.

Comment: So, without the first two lines you're **not** having import errors? (Please, be more precise in your answers). Unfortunately, "I believe it was through cmd" is really not useful, it's like saying "I downloaded it from the internet". If you used the terminal/prompt, we must know the command you used. You also didn't say what operating system and version you're using. Please, try to be more specific in your answers, otherwise nobody could help you.

Comment: @musicamante  Hi! Sorry I need to be a lot more detailed with my answers. 'loadUi' and 'uic' are being used for the rest of my code, but if I were to erase those two lines, then I wouldn't be able to use 'loadUi' or 'uic' as it's needed for the program. I used cmd and used these two commands, 'pip install pyqt5' and used 'pip install pyqt5-tools'. I'm currently using Windows 10 64 bit.

Comment: Again, that's **NOT** what I asked: I specifically told you to check if the imports are successful **without** the first two lines. We need to know if PyQt is *actually* correctly installed, and we can only ensure that by removing the first two lines: different problems (and solutions) might occur whether the standard PyQt sub modules (QtWidgets, QtGui and QtCore most importantly) can be imported or not. If not, then it's possible that PyQt wasn't properly installed. Also, do you have both Python2 *and* Python3 installed? How did you install Python?

Comment: You can even create a basic script with only the standard imports: `from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets`. Then run it in the prompt and see if it throws any error.

Comment: @Ehhh That "error" is a warning from the linter so I recommend you ignore it